# MutableList values are changing when I don't expect them to

Tags: list, kotlin, debugging

So I am doing a coding challenge on code signal, however my code is not executing how I expect it would. I am linearly swapping values in a mutable list of ints and after each iteration I save the original list in a temp variable, however the values in the original list are being changed when I don't want them to.

For b, the original order of the list is (832, 998, 148, 570, 533, 561, 455, 147, 894, 279) and after iterating, the order of b is: (148, 570, 533, 561, 455, 147, 894, 279, 832, 998)

So my question is, why is it doing this and how can I fix it.

```
fun areSimilar(a: MutableList<Int>, b: MutableList<Int>): Boolean {
    var tempList = b
    var tempNumber: Int

    if(a == b) return true

    for(i in 0 until b.size){
        for(j in 0 until b.size){
           tempList = b
            tempNumber = tempList[i]
            tempList[i] = tempList[j]
            tempList[j] = tempNumber

            if (i == 6) println("i: $i | $tempList")

            if(tempList == a) return true
        }
    }

    println(b)

    return false
}


fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    var a = mutableListOf<Int>(832, 998, 148, 570, 533, 561, 894, 147, 455, 279)
    var b = mutableListOf<Int>(832, 998, 148, 570, 533, 561, 455, 147, 894, 279)

    println(areSimilar(a,b))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The assignment `var tempList = b` simply points the `tempList` variable to the same `MutableList` instance as `b`.
Because it's the same list, you can see changes to that list through both variables.

If you want to have 2 different lists, you first need to make an actual copy of your initial list:

```kotlin
var tempList = mutableListOf<Int>().apply { addAll(b) }
```

Or alternatively:

```kotlin
val tempList = ArrayList(b)
val tempList = b.toMutableList() // less clear about the intent of copying the list
```

Using this in every iteration will make a ton of copies of your initial list, which is not ideal. A more efficient option would be to stick with the original `b` but always re-swap the elements to put them back in place after the equality check with `a`.

Comment: Simplest way to get a copy is `b.toMutableList()`.

Comment: @Tenfour04 true, I added this as another alternative. But I don't like this way of creating a copy as it really doesn't reflect the intent. The point of `toMutableList()` is to get a mutable list version of the given collection, it just also happens to create a copy because it's implemented generically for all collections, but the name doesn't convey the intent to "copy".